# An error occurred while trying to read the text from the file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Developing a program that reads text from a file and shows it in a dynamic layout.
However, if you execute the code below, the error as below appears.
Can I get a solution?

[image: logcat]

The code is as below.
ReadFile is a function that reads text from files in file paths received by a factor, and MakeLinearLayout shows some of the text it has read through a TextView in a dynamic layout.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.applandeo.Tempus.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class FriendListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static String FilePath= "/data/data/com.applandeo.materialcalendarsampleapp/files/friendList.txt";

    LinearLayout lm;

    public FriendListActivity(LinearLayout lm) {
        this.lm = lm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_list);

        Button addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddFriendsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });


        lm = findViewById(R.id.ll);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        MakeLinearLayout(lm);
    }

    public String ReadFile (String path){
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuffer.append(line+"\n");
            }

            reader.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsStrting = sw.toString();
            Log.e("Fileread", exceptionAsStrting);

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Failed to read file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return "";
        }
        return strBuffer.toString();
    }

    public void MakeLinearLayout (LinearLayout lm){
        String read = ReadFile(FilePath);

        String[] readArr = read.split("\\-");

        if (readArr != null)
        {
            int nCnt = readArr.length;

            // readArr[0+5n]: phone number, readArr[1+5n]: registration name, readArr [2+5n]: email, readArr[3+5n]: group name, readArr[4+5n]: note
            for (int i=0; i<nCnt; ++i)
            {
                Log.i("ARRTAG", "arr[" + i + "] = " + readArr[i]);
            }

            for(int n=0; ;n++){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                TextView InfoView = new TextView(this);
                InfoView.setText(" " + read);
                //InfoView.setText(" " + readArr[5*n+1] + " " + readArr[5*n+3]);
                ll.addView(InfoView);

                lm.addView(ll);
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "No acquaintances have been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The second error occurred after reflecting the contents of the comment.
[image: logcat2]

Answer (score 0):

Remove below constructor from your activity code. There is no way you can pass parameters to constructor of your activity

```
public FriendListActivity(LinearLayout lm) {
    this.lm = lm;
}
```

Comment: I cleared the code and found another error starting with system_process E/ActivityManager: 0% 25/migration/3:0% user + 0% kernel.
Do you know what's wrong with this?

Comment: When I press the button that moves from another activity to this activity, it occurs and the application shuts down.

Comment: can you show actual error, select error from drop down instead of verbose in Logcat tab

Comment: I have corrected the contents by attaching the error that occurred.
Is this what you want?

Comment: You should have posted your code to start a new activity instead. I bet you still use the `new` operator to create an activity instead of using an intent.

Comment: Well, I was using intents to move activities.
And I'm sorry I didn't write any additional comments here, but I've solved the error by correcting the code that generates dynamic layout after confirming that ARRTAG part is recognized in logcat.